# Is it possible in Vaadin to get the last action at any point?

Tags: vaadin

I have a simple window with components like labels,textfields,buttons.

Is that possible to get the last action happened **without adding listeners** to each component?

I mean something like `UI.getCurrent().getLastAction()`  or `window.getLastAction()`

Comment: Can you describe what you want to achieve in more detail? You clearly have a solution in mind, but what is the problem?